# How to remove last six characters in filename of 50 files

Tags: bash, shell, file, file-rename

I have some 50 files in `D:\dummy\ folder`. It has filenames like

```
Abc_566_1.xml.error
Abc_566_2.xml.error
...
Abc&566_50.xml.error
```

I want a shell script/solution to remove `.error` in all 50 filenames.

Comment: Are you on windows?.

Comment: Please add details of what you have attempted and the obstacles you are facing.

Comment: Hi....WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @error404 How is that appplicable to a shell one-liner question? This is not a programming language question with source to compile.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII I'm told newer Windows versions come with a Linux subsystem ready to use, which includes bash. So it seems entirely possible to mix Windows file paths and shell hackery.

Comment: With `Git Bash` on  `Win10` I normally do bash string manipulations with a loop, to rename files that's why I've ask if you're on Windows, but outside of `Git Bash` I dunno if that will work, except of course for `Win subsystem`

Answer (score 2):

The shell can do quite an amount of string processing, like chopping off substrings at either end of a string. I usually do jobs like yours with

```
 for file in *.error; do
     mv "$file" "${file%.error}"
 done
```

For more on this, read your shell manual, especially the section on parameter expansion.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try:

```
for each in *.error ; do
    mv $each `echo $each | sed -e 's/\.error$//'`
done
```

Comment: You're answering a question without having full picture in mind (OS, terminal, minimal reproducible example, etc.).

Comment: Where does the input to sed come from? This can't work. Please test any proposed solution before posting.